# How to conditionally adjust paddings using css only?

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I'm using materialize css where I have a logo jpeg whose padding is adjusted at the top for medium and up screens. For mobile screen I need to adjust left padding.

For medium and up I have this css style

```
#mylogo {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

and html

```
  <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">
    <img src="images/logo.jpeg" id="mylogo"  alt="Logo">
    My Logo
   </a>
</div>
```

I use the same img tag for screens small and down. What do I have to add or change in my css to have padding-left instead of top in effect for small and down screens?

Comment: Just add padding-left?

Comment: Will not solve it because padding-left is for small to down screens only.  The padding-top is for medium and up, so need some kind of condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries for that.

Considering that materializecss uses three different screen sizes (<=600px for tablets, <=992px for desktops and >992px for everything else) you have to provide the rule only for tablet devices.

In css you should write something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
   #mylogo{
      padding-left: 15px;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) { 
   #mylogo{
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-left:0;
   }
}
```

Comment: just a little typo it's mylogo not myLogo, other than that it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #mylogo {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    #mylogo {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
}
```

On screens up to 480px (you can adjust this), padding left will be added to your image. If a device is at least 481px, your image's padding left will be reset to 0, while padding top will be assigned 15px.

As you can see, you can use different conditions—`min-width` and `max-width` being just two. If you want to see what else is available, check out this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp